# Identifying incorrectly handled InterruptedExceptions via static analysis

Tags: java, static-analysis, findbugs, interrupted-exception

Is there a way to identify (via static analysis, e.g. findbugs or perhaps even checkstyle) when an InterruptedException hasn't been correctly handled (e.g. marking the thread as interrupted or throwing an exception or optionally: having a comment explaining why. The latter option could be ignored?)